# Avoid booting into text mode and boot into GUI directly?

Tags: boot, command-line, gui

Every time I restart Linux, it boots into text mode. And I have to type `startx` to start the GUI.

I've changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` from `"quiet"` to `"quiet splash"` and updated the grub. But still it boots into text mode.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you update grub `sudo update-grub` after changing that parameter ?

Comment: yeah sure, and then I reopened grub and checked and it was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Comment: OK understood. I have a workaround for you.

Comment: And how do you restart by the way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open gedit and paste the following

   `#!/bin/sh -e`

   `sudo startx`

   `exit 0`
2. Save it as anyname.sh (in this example I have saved this file in "dir" folder which is present in your home directory). You might need to change the permissions to this file. To do so type:

   `chmod a+x /home/username/dir/anyname.sh`
3. Then type:

   `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
4. Add the following above the line "exit 0":

   `sudo sh /home/username/dir/anyname.sh`
5. Restart and see if it works.

Comment: (ignore ") ? Why not just remove the " and format as code, for clarity ?

Comment: @markkirby - Am unable to do so, if you can then, you are most welcome!

Comment: @markkirby - Please edit and correct the answer.

Comment: I have now I am off my phone, I see your issue, please see my edit for a way round not being able to use the code button with #

Comment: You should This sounds like a terrible idea, an unprivileged process could modify `~/anyname.sh`.   You could just add `startx` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: `startx` as root by whatever means is a bad idea IMHO: you should focus on why the system is not providing a GUI session automatically i.e. missing or misconfigured display manager (lightdm, gdm etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Just try to reinstall `lightdm` which is the **display manager** running in Ubuntu.

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

And set `lightdm` as the default display manager again by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Restart Ubuntu to see if it works.